# media query: why only the display property doesn't work on my media query

Tags: html, css

So I want to use a media query to adjust my elements. I have a div and an ul element in my nav. I wanted to make the ul display: none; and div display: inline; when my screen is adjusted, but somehow only the display for ul works but display on div doesn't work. I have tried other properties such as background-color and they all seem to work just fine. Please help me T-T!

here is my code

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav .menu {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}

nav {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3vw;
  background-color: crimson;
}

nav .menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <div class="menu">-</div>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: there is a typo in my question, at the second sentence i meant a div and an ul element in my nav element

Comment: You can always [edit] the question and fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put media queries at the bottom of the stylesheet, like this.

```
nav {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3vw;
  background-color: crimson;
}

nav .menu {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav .menu {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes!!! i tried that and it totally works!!! thank you!!! i also solved the problem just now without changing the order but instead i added an !important at the send of the display: inline. BUT i think your answer is the correct way. thank you again!

Comment: You are welcom.

Answer (score 0):

Here, your are setting your div with class menu to display none, you need to do that for the nav instead so this should work.

so Replace:

```css
    nav .menu{
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #fff;
      display: none;
    }
```

With:

```css
    nav {
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #fff;
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your respond and sorry i made a stupid mistake in my code and i just edited it. i wanted to display: inline; for my .menu when the window is adjusted not none. and for the nav bar, i wanted it to be there at all times.

Comment: if you are still facing an issue, can you post your code on codepen or somehting

Comment: I’m new to the coding community, what is codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ check it out, you can create pens and share them so we can see your code in real time, you can also check awesome pens done by awesome people that can help your awesome projects :)

Comment: okay i will check it out. thank you!!